# why hazelcast can not query incorrect result with imap and hazelcastjsonvalue

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I use IMap store data in hazelcast, key is a string, value is a hazelcastjsonvalue. code example:
`

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = "{\"orderId\":\"-20200822-221116-188-quote-100002\",\"securityId\":\"130015\",\"tradingAccount\":\"xtrinterbanktra01\",\"subSystemId\":\"QDM-ESP\",\"userId\":\"xtrinterbankat01\",\"securityExchange\":\"B\",\"systemNodeId\":710,\"quoteId\":\"1598145974197\",\"execId\":\"22550774606679263\",\"investAccount\":\"xtrinterbankinvest01\",\"productAccount\":\"xtrinterbankprod01\",\"assetAccount\":\"xtrinterbankasst01\",\"securityAccount\":\"111010032010000205011\",\"securityType\":\"4\",\"settlType\":\"1\",\"orderModel\":\"legs\",\"orderStatus\":\"8\",\"createdTime\":1598145974,\"createdDate\":\"20200824\",\"tradeDate\":\"20200824\",\"positionFlag\":1,\"price\":111.0,\"orderQty\":1.0E7,\"accumulatedExecQty\":1.0E7,\"lastQty\":1.0E7,\"finalFlag\":true,\"symbol\":\"13国债15\",\"side\":\"1\",\"orderVersion\":2,\"classType\":\"OrderBO\",\"messageId\":87350933198472267,\"uniqueKey\":\"-20200822-221116-188-quote-100002\",\"topicName\":\"order\",\"subject\":\"business/order/130015/B/xtrinterbanktra01/xtrinterbankat01\",\"publisherId\":\"oms-710-9577@168-61-73-136\",\"tenantId\":\"ficc\",\"extFields\":{\"quotaionType\":\"5\",\"clOrdId\":\"-20200822-221116-188-quote-100001\",\"marketIndicator\":\"4\",\"deliveryType\":\"0\",\"transcatTime\":\"1883635200\",\"quoteStaus\":\"16\",\"clearingMethod\":\"13\",\"execType\":\"F\",\"validUnitTime\":\"1883635200\"}}";

    String tableName = "__UT_TestMap";

    IMap map = instance.getMap(tableName);
    map.addIndex(new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH,"orderId"));

    map.put("-20200822-221116-188-quote-100002",json);

    System.out.println(map.entrySet(Predicates.sql("side='1'")));
```

` condition is correct,but result is null,why? when I not add index , the result of query is correct.

Comment: You're doing `map.put(String, TestOrder80);`. What does the class `TestOrder80` look like ?

Comment: sorry，code is not correct，in fact， I am doing map.put(String,json)

Answer (score 0):

In your `map.put`, try changing the value clause from `json` to `new HazelcastJsonValue(json))`

The variable you've named `json` is actually a String, so it's a map of form `Map<String, String>`.

Hazelcast won't search inside a String for a field, because it won't know that it contains any form of structured data. You'll get an `IllegalOperationException` for the code posted.

If you use `new HazelcastJsonValue(json))` for the entry's value, that makes it structured, and you can search (and index) on fields.

Comment: In my Code，change json to HazelcastJsonValue，query return still null，I suppose the json contain chinese string “国债” cause this problem，but I do not know how to fix it？ how to set hazelcast configuration for support chinese character？

Comment: It shouldn't, but can you raise that as a separate question please

Comment: Thanks,I post a separate question like :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607692/why-hazelcast-not-query-incorrect-result-with-imap-and-hazelcastjsonvalue-includ

Comment: [Link to follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607692/why-hazelcast-not-query-incorrect-result-with-imap-and-hazelcastjsonvalue-includ)