# why hazelcast not query incorrect result with imap and hazelcastjsonvalue include chinese character？

Tags: java, hazelcast

when I use hazelcast store data with imap and hazelcastjsonvalue, I can not query incorrect result where sql like " side='1' ". I suppose because the json include Chinese character like "国债". How to fix this? If can I set some configuration of hazelcast to support chinese character. code like this, System.out.println() result is {} , should include json:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = "{\"orderId\":\"-20200822-221116-188-quote-100002\",\"securityId\":\"130015\",\"tradingAccount\":\"xtrinterbanktra01\",\"subSystemId\":\"QDM-ESP\",\"userId\":\"xtrinterbankat01\",\"securityExchange\":\"B\",\"systemNodeId\":710,\"quoteId\":\"1598145974197\",\"execId\":\"22550774606679263\",\"investAccount\":\"xtrinterbankinvest01\",\"productAccount\":\"xtrinterbankprod01\",\"assetAccount\":\"xtrinterbankasst01\",\"securityAccount\":\"111010032010000205011\",\"securityType\":\"4\",\"settlType\":\"1\",\"orderModel\":\"legs\",\"orderStatus\":\"8\",\"createdTime\":1598145974,\"createdDate\":\"20200824\",\"tradeDate\":\"20200824\",\"positionFlag\":1,\"price\":111.0,\"orderQty\":1.0E7,\"accumulatedExecQty\":1.0E7,\"lastQty\":1.0E7,\"finalFlag\":true,\"symbol\":\"13国债15\",\"side\":\"1\",\"orderVersion\":2,\"classType\":\"OrderBO\",\"messageId\":87350933198472267,\"uniqueKey\":\"-20200822-221116-188-quote-100002\",\"topicName\":\"order\",\"subject\":\"business/order/130015/B/xtrinterbanktra01/xtrinterbankat01\",\"publisherId\":\"oms-710-9577@168-61-73-136\",\"tenantId\":\"ficc\",\"extFields\":{\"quotaionType\":\"5\",\"clOrdId\":\"-20200822-221116-188-quote-100001\",\"marketIndicator\":\"4\",\"deliveryType\":\"0\",\"transcatTime\":\"1883635200\",\"quoteStaus\":\"16\",\"clearingMethod\":\"13\",\"execType\":\"F\",\"validUnitTime\":\"1883635200\"}}";

String tableName = "__UT_TestMap";

IMap map = instance.getMap(tableName);
map.addIndex(new IndexConfig(IndexType.HASH,"orderId"));

map.put("-20200822-221116-188-quote-100002",new HazelcastJsonValue(json));

System.out.println(map.entrySet(Predicates.sql("side='1'")));
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug, so I've simplified it a bit and logged it [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/17418)

[Link to original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574076/why-hazelcast-can-not-query-incorrect-result-with-imap-and-hazelcastjsonvalue)